# Nested for Loop Statements Java

Tags: java

I am currently trying to create a nested for Loop statement using java, how do I Create new nested for Loop statement using java which gives the following output:

```
 8
    5 5 5 6 5 8 9 5 6 8 
    7 7 8 7 6 7 8 8 9 7
    8 7 6 7 8 7  5 6 8 7
    9 9 9 8 9 7 9  8 9 9
    7 8 8 7 8 7 8 9 6 8
    6 5 6 4 5 6 5 6 6 6
    7  8 7 7 6 8 7 8 6 6
    5 7 6 7 6 7 6 7 7 7
```

the above numbers are stored in a text file called data1.txt but need to be displayed properly as ints using a 2D array,

Below is my attempt at the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 * class <code>ReadMarks</code> simulates storing student data in a collection.
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 09 Feburary 2014
 */
public class ReadMarks
{


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class ReadMarks
     */
    public ReadMarks()
    {

    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     * 
     */
    public void readMarksData(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
       File dataFile = new File(fileName);
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);

      while( scanner.hasNext() )
      {
         String info = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println(info);
      }
      scanner.close();
   }
   for (int i= 0; i <8; i++)
      for (int j=1; j<=i; j++)
         System.out.print(i*j + "\t");

}
for (int row=1; row<=10; row++)
   {   
      for (int col=1; col<=8; col++)
         System.out.print(row*col + "\t");
      System.out.println();
   }
```

any answers or replies would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It gives that input _excatly_ or input _like_ that?

Comment: What's the logic behind the matrix of numbers? does it have any property that must be satisfied? At first glance it seems like a random distribution of integer numbers in the range 4-9

Comment: it gives those results exactly, basically I have a file called data1.txt which has the above numbers as results and the text file needs to display them as ints using a 2D array

Comment: Looks like the first line gives you the dimensions for the square array and the following lines give you the data. So you know how to dimension the array, and you know exactly how many more lines (or values, if you prefer to think about it that way) you'll need to read. That should be enough to write your control looks without even having to check for end-of-file...

Comment: What's your _question_? What is your current code not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In you code, you do not read numbers from file, you just read whole lines and print it. If you want to read all these ints, you should write something like this:

```
List<Integer> ints = new LinkedList<>();
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    ints.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Now, `ints` variable holds all ints sequentially read form your file. Then we need to print them. As correctly you've noticed, you will need two loops with nesting. You, however, assumed, that 10 rows and 8 columns. What if it doesn't? And what if we want to reformat our output? Let's rather set the number of columns and we will be printing as many rows, as needed:

```
int columnCount = 10;
for (int i = 0, l = ints.size(); i < l;) {
    for (int c = 0; c < columnCount; c++, i++) {
        System.out.printf("%3d", ints.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Now you can just change value of `columnCount` to reformat output. If you need to print this matrix as a regular square (which not really can be possible, as int count doesn't have to sufficient to form regular square), you can calculate square root of the number of int in the `ints` list and compare its square to actual length — if those values match, it means you can set the value of `columnCount` to the square root of int count and be happy with nice square matrix.